# nginx returns 302 FOUND with http instead of https

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http

I try to access `https://seafile.example.com`, which is a proxied application. The application will return 302, but with HTTP instead of HTTPS. Should this be fixed in Nginx or the application (Seafile in this case), I tried it, but don't know what's wrong:

Output from `curl -v https://seafile.example.com`

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Server: nginx/1.12.2
< Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 03:08:02 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
< Location: http://seafile.example.com/accounts/login?next=/
< Content-Language: en
```

I would have expected https://seafile ...

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name seafile.example.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name seafile.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/seafile.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/seafile.example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf;

   proxy_set_header X_Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

   location / {
   proxy_pass         http://192.168.99.12:8000;
   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
   proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
   proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;

   access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
   error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;

   proxy_read_timeout  1200s;

   client_max_body_size 0;
   }
   location /seafhttp {
       rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
       proxy_pass http://192.168.99.12:8082;
       client_max_body_size 0;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_connect_timeout  36000s;
       proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
       proxy_send_timeout  36000s;
       send_timeout  36000s;
   }
```

seahub_settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
SECRET_KEY = "random"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'seahub-db',
        'USER': 'seafile',
        'PASSWORD': 'random',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}

FILE_SERVER_ROOT = 'https://seafile.example.com'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.example.com'        # smpt server
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''    # username and domain
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''    # password
EMAIL_PORT = 25
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'seafile@example.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'seafile@example.com'
```

ccnet.conf

```
[General]
USER_NAME = seafile
ID = ranodm
NAME = seafile
SERVICE_URL = https://seafile.example.com

[Client]
PORT = 13419

[Database]
ENGINE = mysql
HOST = 127.0.0.1
PORT = 3306
USER = seafile
PASSWD = random
DB = ccnet-db
CONNECTION_CHARSET = utf8
```

Comment: That redirect looks like it comes from your application. You should first attempt to reconfigure the application.

Comment: Yes I thought so too, but in seafile all URLs point to the https version... (seahub_settings, ccnet.conf)

Comment: If you think it is from nginx, then please post the nginx configuration. At minimum, the complete `server` block.

Comment: updated the first post

Comment: There are no redirects to HTTP there. Check the application _again_.

Comment: did, don't know where to look else, can't I force a rewrite to https via nginx?

Comment: You can't force a rewrite to https because it's already https! That would just give you an infinite loop. The browser would tell you this redirect will never complete properly. At this point you should contact the application's developer, I think.

Comment: With rewrite I mean a rewrite from the applications response.

Comment: Check `proxy_redirect` directive. But that should be last resort. It's better to fix you application if possible

Comment: Have you tried using `$scheme://$server_name$request_uri/` ? This might resolve the lattermost request protocol. It's possible, but can't test right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name seafile.example.com;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://192.168.99.12:8000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect http://192.168.99.12:8000/ https://seafile.example.com/;
                proxy_read_timeout  1200s;
                client_max_body_size 0;
        }
        ssl     on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/seafile.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/seafile.example.com-0001/privkey.pem;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
}
```